# Get an object with submit binding of KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

### The goal

Get an object with submit binding of KnockoutJS.

### The problem

I need to get the object instead of the element when I submit some form.

[Here, on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8zPT/1/), open your console and then click on `add button` of some item. You'll receive the `Products object` and here everything is right. But [here, also in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8zPT/2/), when you click on `add button` your response will be the element instead of the object — and I need the object.

### The difference between the codes

Look to this function when I add:

```
self.add = function (item) {
    var i = self.products.indexOf(item);
    self.products()[i].isAdded(true);
};
```

But, when the binding is `submit`, the `item` parameter is different from response that `click` binding returns.

### My scenario

In my real application, there is two ViewModels [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/G8zPT/6/). I thought it would be simpler, but unfortunately, it isn't.

Someone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the `$data` object when calling the function on the submit. Otherwise it will automatically pass the form object.

For example:

```
  <!-- ko ifnot:isAdded -->
  <form data-bind="submit: function() { $parent.add($data); }">
  <button data-bind="ifnot:isAdded" class="btn btn-small action add">
      <i class="icon-plus">Add</i>
  </button>
  </form>
  <!-- /ko -->
```

Here's a working update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G8zPT/4/

Comment: And what if the `add` function is a method of an object? For example, `Summary.add($data)`? I have to do something like this?: `$parent.Summary.add($data)` because if yes, doesn't work.

Comment: Well the `add` function in the jsfiddle you did is a method of an object and that works. Maybe try `$root.Summary.add($data);`. That will work from the base of your view model. You might be looking in the wrong context. (Here's a working fiddle with $parent.Summary.add($data): http://jsfiddle.net/G8zPT/5/)

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge why don't you post a jsfiddle with the code that isn't working?

Comment: Updated the main post, dhsto. Take a look if possible. And thanks about your help!

Comment: You are having more problems than the original question. Here's a working fiddle... do a diff to see the differences: http://jsfiddle.net/G8zPT/9/ -- The big issue is just being aware of the context of variables in knockout. Also, check out the changes to the `self.add` and `self.remove` function. You will see it's a lot simpler.

Comment: I'm feeling that we are almost there, but some troubles are remaining. When I add something, this is showed by console: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'isAdded' ` — and yes, I've changed the binding of submit.

Comment: What is the object that it's calling 'isAdded' on? It's updating the observable fine in the fiddle.

Comment: I found the problem, dhsto. The list of available products aren't providing by Knockout, but yes by C# and thats why the Summary VM can't get the object. Unfortunately, I can't loop the products from database by Knockout, I need a C# foreach instead of KnockoutJS virtual foreach. Any idea?

Comment: You don't need to use a C# foreach (I assume your using asp.net mvc?). You can just do something like `ko.observableArray(JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ProductsFromYourController))'));` in your view. Just make sure `ProductsFromYourController` is a list that has a `name`, `desc` and an `isAdded` property. (You might need to escape any single quotes when doing @Html.Raw)

Comment: I meant to say, 'is a list of objects where the objects have properties name, desc, and isAdded'. One thing you could also try is have an ajax call to the webserver to fill the products array (have C# return the array of products as JSON). This is way beyond the original question though, so good luck!

Comment: Oh my god. There is too much logic involved in my controller. I'm in a dilemma. >_>

Comment: Well, you have to pass a list of Products from the Controller to the View anyways. You could just do something like `var p = []; @foreach(var product in ViewBag.Products) { <text>p.push(new Product(@product.Name, @product.Desc);</text> }`, then pass `p` into the `SummaryViewModel`. My razor syntax might be a bit off, but it should help you try to figure this out.